# BBC, Playtime: Summer fair, don't understand certain parts from audio program

Tags: meaning, translation

The radio program is here:

http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/radio/playtime/playtime_20150512-0900a.mp3

Don't understand the following fragments:

```
00:40 – There are lots of brightly …   …
01:30 hairy …
02:20 your coconut …. at?
04:10 – gently lowered to … the duck,
05:00 listen to the … band?
06:40 … your arms round each other
10:08 said lady …. Sticker??
10:15 Grumbly ?– 
11:20 wanted to win a prize …. Jane,
```

Could someone please write it down for me?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BBC Schools programme**

> 00:40  brightly-coloured stalls selling toys, cakes...
> 01:30  hard and very hairy shells.
> 02:20  Keep your eyes on your coconut you're aiming at
> 04:10  lower it towards the duck
> 05:00  listen to the brass band
>
> 06:40  circle your arms round each other
>
> 10:08  "Would you like a sticker?"
>
> 10:15 "No thank you," said Hugh, rather grumbly  (?grumpily)
>
> 11:20  ...wanted to win a prize," moaned Jane,

Comment: First sentence: selling toys, (and here: plums ...?), cakes

Comment: @John "... toys, *plants*, and delicious cakes"