# BBC, Playtime: Summer clothes, don't understand certain parts from audio program

Tags: meaning, translation

The radio program is here:

http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/radio/playtime/playtime_20150602-0900a.mp3

I don't get the words in (...) included or doesn't understand the meaning.
If anyone could fill the (...) or explain the sentence would be great.
Thanks!

```
And made pointed toes when mum put them on – 10:20 (explain please)
And his … wedling blue cape 10:25?
Bright yellow wheels, you could put it along? 11:10 (explain please)
Mum fished …. Her magic bag … ? 11:20
We don’t have a ….. said 11:28 kicking the …. ?
Look What I brought along for You, a …  for You Luke 11:38
I’ve got … for Boo and the ….  And the floating vest – 12:05 
He was ? with tiny white dots 12:15? 
And mum laughed, he got quite … ?12:20
D ……in the water ?12:28
And looked …. His nose and jumped in 12:30
To the fingers wrinkled like …. 13:00
Snap card? 13:30
And sucked her ….   13:48
Ice … beginning with b 13:55
… rubbish for a picninc 14:30 
And  the s … ? 14:40
```

Thank You

Comment: Sorry, John, ELU does not provide a transcription service. Contact BBC and ask them for a transcript.

Comment: They don't provide the people with the transcripts on their official webpage  so I don't think they would publish only for me on demand ... In the past there were kind people here who helped me with certain phrases in previous chapters, I really hope someone could help me with above ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for a transcript from a radio show - not about English language usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is (1) asking multiple questions (2) involving transcription.

Comment: Can you please paste the snippet from the rules of ELU about transcription requests?

Comment: @John: Hi! Use http://transcribe.wreally.com/ to easily transcribe the audio recording. I've never tried transferring audio to text file format but I tried it for the first time today (using this web app). It worked beautifully though it took a lot of time. I really wish I could post the transcript here but I can't do so.

Comment: @AishwaryaAR How did you manage to redirect mp3 to a microphone input .. As I saw that is the only one option to try with automatic engine ...

Comment: Ok I managed to do it. Indeed it is awesome ... it works really great as for the machine :)

Comment: There really are far too many gaps to fill. You're asking strangers to sit, listen and write the missing words for *what?  Users like to be challenged, they want to deepen their understanding of the *language*,  they also want to share that knowledge, but this question ONLY helps you. Nobody else will care, nobody else will look back at this post and think "That was helpful, I learned something new today.".You have got away with asking this type of questions a couple of times, I even lent a hand once in the comments section , but now you are taking advantage of people's good will.

Comment: [BBC, Playtime: **Picnic**, don't understand certain parts from audio program](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248925/bbc-playtime-picnic-dont-understand-certain-parts-from-audio-program?noredirect=1#comment540635_248925) (Now deleted) and [BBC, Playtime: **Summer fair**, don't understand certain parts from audio program](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247873/bbc-playtime-summer-fair-dont-understand-certain-parts-from-audio-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the BBC podcast link, right click and select 'Save as..'. This will enable you to save the audio file as a download having an mp3 format. Once you've saved the podcast to your PC, go to the link that I gave you(transcribe.wreally.com) and sign up for a 7 days free trial. Once you've provided your e-mail ID and signed up, you can use that free trial. You will be led to a page that will ask you to upload the saved audio file(the one that you downloaded) . After that, you simply need to click the play button and change the speed of the audio file as per your requirement(you can step it down to 0.5x) and comfortably start typing(in a separate section provided on the same page) simultaneously. Since the audio file is played very slowly, you can very easily figure out what is being said.
[image]

[image]

PS: I didn't get enough space to post this suggestion in the comment section. My apologies for posting it as an answer.